# Требуется переработать код для отчёта(canvas)

Tags: php

есть ресурс https://canvasjs.com/php-charts/stacked-column-100-chart/

Там можно менять данные я поставил заводы по производству пластиковых труб [Пример code.re/2FKqG1p6](https://code.re/2FKqG1p6)

Есть задача автоматизации в плане чтоб руками не забивать в типичные array данные, предположил что можно сделать массив

```
$data=array('Завод 1'=>array('Пластиковая труба ф10'=>'100 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф20'=>'120 шт','Пластиковая труба ф30'=>'150 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф40'=>'110 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф50'=>'160 шт', 'Платиковая труба ф60'=>'90 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф70'=>'115 шт' ),
'Завод 2'=>array('Пластиковая труба ф10'=>'105 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф20'=>'125 шт','Пластиковая труба ф30'=>'155 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф40'=>'115 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф50'=>'165 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф60'=>'95 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф70'=>'120 шт' ),
'Завод 3'=>array('Пластиковая труба ф10'=>'110 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф20'=>'130 шт','Пластиковая труба ф30'=>'160 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф40'=>'120 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф50'=>'170 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф60'=>'100 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф70'=>'125 шт' ),
'Завод 4'=>array('Пластиковая труба ф10'=>'115 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф20'=>'135 шт','Пластиковая труба ф30'=>'165 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф40'=>'125 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф50'=>'175 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф60'=>'105 шт', 'Пластиковая труба ф70'=>'130 шт' ));
```

И его уже как то через foreach разложить. В идеале можно будет брать из mysql данные, но пока хочу просто взять массив и его уже делать в отчёт.
Помогите с кодом. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Ставлю +, но видимо полностью допиливать мне) всё таки  дело в отчете, а не в массиве,но мне понравилось)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для генерации фейковых данных в `php` можно воспользоваться тремя функциями:

- [range($start, $end, $step)](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.range.php) - создает массив от *$start* до *$end* с шагом *$step*;
- [mt_rand($min, $max)](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mt-rand.php) - генерирует случайное значение от *$min* до *$max*;
- [array_rand($array, $num)](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-rand.php) - выбирает *$num* случайных ключей из массива.

Конкретный пример для вашего случая:

```
$data = [];

// Заводы.
$plants = range(1, mt_rand(8, 12));

// Диаметры труб.
$diamPipes = range(10, 70, 10);

// Количество труб.
$countPipes = range(0, 150);

// Строим заводы.
foreach($plants as $plant) {
  // Производим трубы.
  foreach($diamPipes as $dia) {
    $data["Завод $plant"]["Платиковая труба ф$dia"] = $countPipes[array_rand($countPipes)].' шт';
  }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Либо воспользоваться библиотекой [**Faker**](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker).